# Drupal 7 - Hosting New/Multiple Domains Seamlessly With Same Site Code, Themes, Modules, Data etc

Tags: drupal, drupal-multi-domain

I would like to use Drupal 7 to support two domains with same code, themes, modules and even database and content, completely transparent to the end-user.

So, user of exmaple1.com would see only exmaple1.com and user of example2.com would see only example2.com (not be redirected to example1.com).  To complicate matters, I already have example1.com legacy, which cannot change.

Closest I have come -

1) using apache virtual host to proxy requests for both domains to same drupal htdcos directory.
2)  setup sites for each domain as per https://drupal.org/node/53705.
    a) Modify the base URL within settings.php file under example2.com directory

But, still, users of example2.com are redirected to example1.com(?!).  In fact, I looked into my default settings.php file and found the baseURL field is commented out.  A directory search for my sites base URL returned no results, suggesting it is set somewhere in the database?  WHERE?  I looked into tables like url_alias - no records.  Can this is set to some variable that reads the HTTP request for the base URL and not be hard-coded as it seems to be?

I have already reviewed solutions that "fix" the base_URL in settings.php, apache virtual host, doing HTTP redirect/rewrite in .htaccess, pathauto modules, backup/migrate and also multi-site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you read an old documentation for multisites on (2). For Drupal 7 check https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site.

But you need to set up [Symlinks (Symbolic links)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to achieve that. I don't think you need a multisite here if both sites use the same files and database.

Comment: Correct.  Multi-site is not applicable for using same files and database.  There is another Drupal module, Domain Access, that  handles this issue.  But I have been unable to get it to work, unfortunately, so I did not answer my own question.  It messes up the legacy site (styles are lost).  Removing the module restores the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the useful link below for Drupal 7 multisite install,

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-windows/

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-linux/